# Mongoose isModified and isNew

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have seen this example in different tutorials and I just wonder why this works with new documents. Are new documents considered modified? Shouldn't we use `this.isNew || this.isModified` instead of just isModified?

```
  try {
      if (!this.isModified("password")) {
        return next();
      }
      let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
      this.password = hashedPassword;
      return next();
  } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation about this is not very clear, so let's learn this by trying:

```js
schema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  console.log("password isModified: ", this.isModified("password"));
  console.log("isNew: ", this.isNew);
  next();
});
```

When we create a new user, the output will be like this:

```
password isModified:  true
isNew:  true
```

So we see the `this.isModified("password")` is `true`. So we can understand that `this.isModified("password")` is also true for new documents.

Comment: Yes I see that but I don't know why is this. It's a little bit confusing because you have a method to see if is new or not. IsModified should return false with a new document in my opinion.

Comment: @DiegoPerdomo I agree with you, but this is how mongoose works, so we don't have any control about this.